Digital Root Function returns "undefined"
I'm new to programming!
Trying to write a function that obtains the digital root of a number.
Currently struggling with the "for loop" and "if else" portion of the formula that returns "undefined". Can you please give me any feedback and explain where my errors are specifically?
function digitalRoot(n) {
  let sum = 0;// define variable for loop calculations
  let str = n.toString(10,'')// convert number into string
  if (str.length === 1) { // test if string length is more than 1 character
    return str * 1; // if 1 character, return that string value and convert it back to a number
    }
  else {
    return 
    let strArray = parseInt(str.split(','))// if more than 1 character, split string into individual characters & convert back to numbers
    for (let i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) { // sum up the numbers and repeat until there is just a single digit result
      sum += strArray[i];
    }  
  }
}


You don’t return anything in your else block

Why are you returning immediately the else section is entered, thus never executing the code that immediately follows it?

a side note. n.toString(10,'') - as far as I know Number.prototype.toString takes an optional single argument. What do you think the second argument '' is? This won't break anything, just a side note

Thank you for the help so far and I will be more aware of "return" use in the future.
Having removed this, the function still returns undefined - I am really stuck and appreciate the help!

I thought I needed to define the separator, but understand that is not the case. To be clear, the first argument of toString is clarifying what base of number system is being used, correct?

Yes, that's correct. It defaults to 10, so there's no need to specify it explicitly.

You need return sum; at the end of the else block.

There's also a random return at the beginning of the else block. Remove that and return sum at the end of the else block. Also, you don't need else here since the if ends in a return. See how to debug small programs. You should be able to figure this out by adding console.log("HERE") to various lines of your program. If you did that, you'd see that none of the logic in the else block ever executes.

Thank you all - I understand that my errors were using return too early in the function, and I was missing the unary + to ensure the loop was adding the values as numbers. Added recursion function call to the end and it works!

function digitalRoot(n) {
let sum = 0;// define variable for loop calculations
let str = n.toString() // convert number into string
if (str.length === 1) { // test if string length is more than 1 character
return +str; // if 1 character, return that string value and convert it back to a number
}
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { // sum up the numbers and repeat until there is just a single digit result
sum += +str[i];
}
return digitalRoot(sum);
}
